# SIGSEGV using fork to run geant4

Tags: c++, function, fork, segmentation-fault

I am running into a problem when I run my code which uses fork to create a child Geant4 process but only if I use a function.  I can call my function multiple times in a row without issue and so I think the problem must occur right before termination of main and thus all that I care about is completed successfully.  I don't think it is good programming practice to ignore errors even if they don't affect the results, so I would like to know what is causing the error.
This is my code without the function (no SIGSEGV):

```
#include <iostream>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

string runFile;
cout << "Enter run macro file name: ";
cin >> runFile;
cout << "Running './disk " << runFile << "'" << endl;
const char* file = runFile.c_str();

const char* programPath =
        "/home/fred/Documents/DIRC_Research/disk-build/disk";

    pid_t pid = fork();

    switch (pid)
    {
        case -1:
            std::cerr << "fork() failed.\n";
            exit(1);
        case 0:
            execl(programPath, "disk", file, NULL);
            std::cerr << "execl() failed!";
            exit(1);
        default:
            std::cout << "Process created with pid " << pid << std::endl;
            int* status;

            waitpid(pid, status, 0);

            std::cout << "Process exited with " << WEXITSTATUS(status) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This is it using the function

```
#include <iostream>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void runDisk(const char*);

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    string runFile;
    cout << "Enter run macro file name: ";
    cin >> runFile;
    cout << "Running './disk " << runFile << "'" << endl;
    const char* file = runFile.c_str();
    runDisk(file);

    return 0;
}

// Function to run disk Geant4 simulation with a run macro file
void runDisk(const char* runFile)
{
    const char* programPath =
        "/home/fred/Documents/DIRC_Research/disk-build/disk";

    pid_t pid = fork();

    switch (pid)
    {
        case -1:
            std::cerr << "fork() failed.\n";
            exit(1);
        case 0:
            execl(programPath, "disk", runFile, NULL);
            std::cerr << "execl() failed!";
            exit(1);
        default:
            std::cout << "Process created with pid " << pid << std::endl;
            int* status;

            waitpid(pid, status, 0);

            std::cout << "Process exited with " << WEXITSTATUS(status) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The code which uses a function gives a SIGSEGV before terminating even if I make the function inline. I would really like to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured it out at least as far as the function usage goes.  I have put

```
int status = 0;

waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

std::cout << "Process exited with " << WEXITSTATUS(status) << std::endl;
```

rather than

```
int* status;

waitpid(pid, status, 0);

std::cout << "Process exited with " << WEXITSTATUS(status) << std::endl;
```

And now I no longer am haunted by SIGSEGV. As for the reason it works when not in a function is still a mystery to me, perhaps it has something to do with the function deleting `status`.